# Monitoring progress of a parallel computation in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, progress-bar, parallel-processing

I'm building a large `ParallelTable`, and would like to maintain some sense of how the computation is going. For a non parallel table the following code does a great job:

```
counter = 1;
Timing[
 Monitor[
  Table[
   counter++
  , {n, 10^6}];
 , ProgressIndicator[counter, {0, 10^6}]
 ]
]
```

with the result `{0.943512, Null}`. For the parallel case, however, it's necessary to make the `counter` shared between the kernels:

```
counter = 1;
SetSharedVariable[counter];
Timing[
 Monitor[
  ParallelTable[
   counter++
  , {n, 10^4}];
 , ProgressIndicator[counter, {0, 10^4}]
 ]
]
```

with the result `{6.33388, Null}`. Since the value of `counter` needs to be passed back and forth between the kernels at every update, the performance hit is beyond severe. Any ideas for how to get some sense of how the computation is going? Perhaps letting each kernel have its own value for `counter` and summing them at intervals? Perhaps some way of determining what elements of the table have already been farmed out to the kernels?

Comment: Perhaps it should be highlighted that the second loop does a factor of 100 less iterations than the first one, so the performance hit is more severe then is apparent at first sight.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You nearly gave the answer yourself, when you said "Perhaps letting each kernel have its own value for counter and summing them at intervals?".

Try something like this:

```
counter = 1;
SetSharedVariable[counter];
ParallelEvaluate[last = AbsoluteTime[]; localcounter = 1;]
Timing[Monitor[
  ParallelTable[localcounter++; 
    If[AbsoluteTime[] - last > 1, last = AbsoluteTime[]; 
     counter += localcounter; localcounter = 0;], {n, 10^6}];, 
  ProgressIndicator[counter, {0, 10^6}]]]
```

Note that it takes longer than your first single-CPU case only because it actually does something in the loop.

You can change the test AbsoluteTime[] - last > 1 to something more frequent like AbsoluteTime[] - last > 0.1.

Comment: Excellent idea! However, all those calls to `AbsoluteTime[]` seem to induce quite a nasty hit as well. My solution is to simply allow the `localcounter` to run up to, say, 10000, at which point it dumps into the global `counter`. Thanks!

Comment: Fair enough, it does depend on what you do in the loop. I find that AbsoluteTime[] takes about as long as 7 increment (++) operations which isn't too bad: Compare k = 0; Timing[Table[k++; k++; k++; k++; k++; k++; k++;, {10^6}];] with Timing[Table[AbsoluteTime[];, {10^6}];].

Comment: Using `AbsoluteTiming` instead of timing in the code in your answer I get 18s, while using the dump every 10000 technique, I get 2.5s. Since the communication between the kernels happens a good deal more often in the latter case, I can only assume that it's  `AbsoluteTime[]` that's adding so much more time.

Comment: Actually, testing the code snippets in your comment, I found that the first took 5s vs 28s for the second. Wonder what's different between our systems that makes `AbsoluteTime[]` take so much longer for me.

Answer (score 5):

This seems hard to solve. From the [manual](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ParallelTools/tutorial/ParallelEvaluation.html):

> Unless you use shared variables, the parallel evaluations performed
>   are completely independent and cannot influence each other.
>   Furthermore, any side effects, such as assignments to variables, that
>   happen as part of evaluations will be lost. The only effect of a
>   parallel evaluation is that its result is returned at the end.

However, a rough progress indicator can still be gotten using the old `Print`statement:

[image]

Comment: An addition: one can use `PrintTemporary` instead of `Print`. I think in this case this function is very useful.

Comment: I already tried that. It doesn't seem to work in the parallel case.

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries: You can use a shared function to ensure PrintTemporary always runs on the master kernel: SetSharedFunction[ParallelPrintTemporary];
ParallelPrintTemporary[e_] := PrintTemporary[e];
Timing[ParallelTable[
   If[Mod[n, 100000] == 0, ParallelPrintTemporary[n]];, {n, 10^6}];]

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to put a trace on LinkWrite and LinkRead and modify their tracing messages to do some useful accounting.

First, launch some parallel kernels:

```
LaunchKernels[]
```

This will have set up the link objects for the parallel kernels.

Then define an init function for link read and write counters:

```
init[] := Map[(LinkWriteCounter[#] = 0; LinkReadCounter[#] = 0) &, Links[]]
```

Next, you want to increment these counters when their links are being read from or written to:

```
Unprotect[Message];
Message[LinkWrite::trace, x_, y_] := LinkWriteCounter[x[[1, 1]]] += 1;
Message[LinkRead::trace, x_, y_] := LinkReadCounter[x[[1, 1]]] += 1;
Protect[Message];
```

Here, `x[[1,1]]` is the LinkObject in question.

Now, turn on tracing on LinkWrite and LinkRead:

```
On[LinkWrite];
On[LinkRead];
```

To format the progress display, first shorten the LinkObject display a bit, since they are rather verbose:

```
Format[LinkObject[k_, a_, b_]] := Kernel[a, b]
```

And this is a way to display the reads and writes dynamically for the subkernel links:

```
init[];
Dynamic[Grid[Join[
  {{"Kernel", "Writes", "Reads"}}, 
  Map[{#, LinkWriteCounter[#]/2, LinkReadCounter[#]/2} &, 
  Select[Links[], StringMatchQ[First[#], "*subkernel*"] &
]]], Frame -> All]]
```

(I'm dividing the counts by two, because every link read and write is traced twice).

And finally test it out with a 10,000 element table:

```
init[];
ParallelTable[i, {i, 10^4}, Method -> "FinestGrained"];
```

If everything worked, you should see a final progress display with about 5,000 read and writes for each kernel:

[image: Screen shot of the kernel session]

There is medium performance penalty for this: 10.73s without the monitor, and 13.69s with the monitor. And of course using the "FinestGrained" option is not the most optimal method to use for this particular parallel computation.

Answer (score 1):

You can get some ideas from the package `` Spin`System`LoopControl` `` developed by Yuri Kandrashkin:

[image: screenshot from Spin Algebra home]

[Announce of the `` Spin` `` package:](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/msg/150979628634e543)

```
Hi group,

I have prepared the package Spin` that consists of several applications
which are designed for research in the area of magnetic resonance and 
spin chemistry and physics.

The applications Unit` and LoopControl` can be useful to a broader
audience.

The package and short outline is available at:
http://sites.google.com/site/spinalgebra/.

Sincerely,
Yuri Kandrashkin.
```

Comment: @Sjoerd I have not tested it but probably not. I posted this as an example of similar functionality which can be useful if someone wish to implement it.

Comment: @Sjoerd Probably it is not too difficult to extend this approach for working in parallel. The only thing we need to realize is how it is possible to change value of `Dynamic` variables from within a parallel subkernel.