# Monitor output of a function parallelized through ParallelMap

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, parallel-processing

```
mle[data_] := ArgMin[
              {-LogLikelihood[twoState[a, b, 60, 0.2], data],  
               Element[{a, b}, Reals] && a > 0 && b > 0}, 
              {a, b}]

ParallelMap[mle, {BG6, BG3, DC5}]
```

I'm executing the mle function in parallel over independent datasets using ParallelMap. I'd like to see the output as each parallel evaluation finishes. I looked at the documentation for Monitor, but its not clear to me how to use it here. It looks I need to a vector to hold the results using something like:

```
SharedVariable[params]
```

And then append the output of mle to params inside a call to Monitor, but I don't know the syntax to do this.

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/7352461/615464

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to view the result when it is ready, you can print it before returning.

```
mle[data_] := Module[{result},
    result = ArgMin[
          {-LogLikelihood[twoState[a, b, 60, 0.2], data],  
           Element[{a, b}, Reals] && a > 0 && b > 0}, 
          {a, b}];
    Print[result];
    Return[result];
];
```

You can replace the call to `Print` if you want to do something more complicated, like calling `Monitor`.